# Plot dates that occur within a week

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is my challenge and not sure how to proceed
I have a list of dates and those dates occur within a couple of weeks that I want to track. I want to ultimately plot the occurrences of those dates within the week. Here is the example.
Lets take 3 weeks that I want to track

```
Week of June 20th - June 20 2016 - June 25 2016 (5 day work week)
Week of June 27th - June 27 2016 - July 1 2016
Week of July 4th - July 4 2016 - July 8 2016
```

I want to track total of 9 events on dates that fall within each of the weeks.

```
Event #1 occurs June 21
Events 2 through 4 occurs June 25
Event 5 occurs June 28
Event 6 occurs July 1
Events 7 and 8 occurs July 4
Event 9 occurs July 8
```

Other way of representing is that , I have these specific dates

```
6/21/2016
6/25/2016
6/25/2016
6/25/2016
6/28/2016
7/1/2016
7/4/2016
7/4/2016
7/8/2016
```

In the x axis of the graph, I want to put week1 through week6.
Y axis - I want to plot activity count.
For week1, I expect to see count of 4 (because there is 1 occurrence of 6/21 and 3 occurrences of 6/25), For week2, I expect to see count of 2 because I have one occurrence of 6/28 and 1 occurrence of 7/1. 
Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what the desired graph would look like.
You can use the WEEKNUM() function to group the dates into their corresponding week.

Comment: I modified the question to mention about my desired graph. Weeknum() function will give me the week number in the year. For me, week#1 is June 20th week. So that function wont help ,  I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also not quite sure what the result should look like, but you can use the `WEEKNUM` function like this

```
           A          B
 1    Date         Week
 2    6/21/2016    ="Week " & WEEKNUM(A2)-weeknum($A$2)+1
```

Then Insert Chart, or Insert PivotTable